# Kubernetes Ingress Controller on Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, kubernetes, coreos

Is there anything special about running ingress controllers on Kubernetes CoreOS Vagrant Multi-Machine? I followed the example but when I run `kubectl -f` I do not get an address.

Example:

http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/ingress.html#single-service-ingress

Setup:

https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-vagrant.html

I looked at networking in kubernetes. Everything looks like it should run without further configuration.

My goal is to create a local testing environment before I build out a production platform. I'm thinking there's something about how they setup their virtualbox networking. I'm about to dive into the CoreOS cloud config but thought I would ask first.

**UPDATE**

Yes I'm running an ingress controller.

https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/Ingress/controllers/nginx-alpha/rc.yaml

It runs without giving an error. It's just when I run `kubectl -f` I do not get an address. I'm thinking there's either two things:

1. I have to do something extra in networking for CoreOS-Kubernetes vagrant multi-node.
2. It's running right, but I'm point my localhost to the wrong IP. I'm using a 172.17.4.x ip, I also have 10.0.0.x . I can access services through the 172.17.4.x using a NodePort, but I can get to my Ingress.

Here is the code:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress:0.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 80
```

**Update 2**
Output of commands:

`kubectl get pods`

```
NAME                  READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
echoheaders-kkja7     1/1       Running   0          24m
nginx-ingress-2wwnk   1/1       Running   0          25m
```

`kubectl logs nginx-ingress-2wwnk --previous`

```
Pod "nginx-ingress-2wwnk" in namespace "default": previous terminated container "nginx" not found
```

`kubectl exec nginx-ingress-2wwnk -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}
http {


}%
```

I'm running an echoheaders service on NodePort. When I type the node IP and port on my browser, I get that just fine.

I restarted all nodes in virtualbox too.

Comment: Are you running an Ingress controller (and if so which one)? Please see http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/ingress.html#ingress-controllers and https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/Ingress/controllers. You probably want one of the nginx controllers, or the serviceloadbalancer: https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/service-loadbalancer

Comment: Yes, using an ingress-rc. Updated question with details.

Comment: Can you please post the output from the debug steps on this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-containers/JeagxWTEYtQ.

Comment: Please see update 2. I'm not sure how they're suppose to look. If there's nothing abnormal I will start testing on AWS and write it off to vagrant networking.

Comment: Just to confirm, I want to access the node IP to test the ingress controller, not the docker overlay IP for the pod. I have a 172.17.4.201 IP for my vagrant node which I type in my browser and get an immediate 404 error. I have a 10.2.90.2 IP for my pod and that hangs which goes to a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a lot help from kubernetes irc and slack, I fixed this a while back. If I remember correctly, I had the ingress service listening on a port that was already being used, I think for vagrant. These commands really help:

```
kubectl get pod <nginx-ingress pod> -o json
kubectl exec <nginx-ingress pod> -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
kubectl get pods -o wide
kubectl logs <nginx-ingress pod> --previous
```

Comment: Do you remember what you did to fix this? While all the containers start up and I can connect to the ports on the pods directly on the ports, the ingress-lb keeps returning connection refused when I try on the IP. Even followed this example down to a tee - https://medium.com/@rothgar/exposing-services-using-ingress-with-on-prem-kubernetes-clusters-f413d87b6d34#.cclkvdn9s

Comment: Try help on the kubernetes slack channel, they're really nice and got me up: http://slack.kubernetes.io/ . . . . . For my case, I was running CoreOS in Vagrant with Kubernetes. That Vagrant setup was taking a port needed by the kubernetes ic. I changed the ports on Vagrant and it was fixed. Checking the logs helps a lot, not just kubernetes, but whatever's acting as the load balancer in this case traefik.